# How to shutdown DLL with user-interface threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll, mfc

I have made a DLL with a function that opens a non-modal window.

```
class CMainFrame : public CFrameWnd
{
protected:
    CMainFrame() {}
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CMainFrame)
public:
    virtual void PostNcDestroy()
    { AfxPostQuitMessage(0); }
public:
    virtual ~CMainFrame() {}
};
IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CMainFrame, CFrameWnd)

class CDllApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    CDllApp() :
        m_pDocTemplate(NULL)
    {};
public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance()
    {
        CWinApp::InitInstance();
        m_pDocTemplate = new CMultiDocTemplate(IDR_MAINFRAME, RUNTIME_CLASS(C3DGraphDoc),
            RUNTIME_CLASS(CMainFrame), RUNTIME_CLASS(C3DGraphView));
        return TRUE;
    }
public:
    CMultiDocTemplate* m_pDocTemplate;
};

CDllApp theApp;

class C3DThread : public CWinThread
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(C3DThread)
public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance()
    {
        theApp.m_pDocTemplate->OpenDocumentFile(NULL);
    }
};
IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(C3DThread, CWinThread)

void __stdcall ExportedFunction()
{
    AfxBeginThread(RUNTIME_CLASS(C3DThread));
}
```

If I close all windows before exiting main application, then all looks fine, otherwise my threads hang up. So, I think I need to clean up by closing all open documents and I wonder what would be the simplest way to do it gracefully. `m_pDocTemplate->CloseAllDocuments()` from theApp doesn't work, since frame windows for documents belong to different threads.

Comment: Why are you creating a document on a different thread? Normally all document/views will be created on the UI thread. Worker threads can use those docs but don't own them.

Comment: @snowdude, they are created on UI threads, there're no worker threads here. If you mean 'create a single UI thread that'd manage all windows', then I'll still need synchronizing with that thread on exit (and also when opening/closing windows) - this would probably make things more complex.

Comment: Yes, create a single UI thread. Then the UI thread can wait on other threads to finish during ExitInstance.